# Ruby: compare dates as keys in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key, comparison

I have code which uses information from a MySQL database to generate a hash representing a roster/rota like:

```
hash = {DateObject1 => "Fender", DateObject2 => "Leyla", DateObject3 => "Eiffel", DateObject4 => "Minkowski", DateObject5 => "Fender", DateObject6 => "Eiffel" etc.}
```

where `DateObjects` are class `Date` and names are `String`.
I then have an array of names e.g.

```
itemarray = ["Eiffel", "Fender", "Leyla", "Minkowski", etc ]
```

And I run this code, to find all dates associated with a given name and detect conditions such as two resulting dates being within a specified distance.

```
class RotaIteration <
Struct.new(:whichiteration, :maxShifts1, :weekdays_too_close1, :weekends_too_close1, :weekday_Saturday_too_close1,
:shifts_too_close1, :max14days, :messes1, :iteration_cost1, :rotamd51)
end

def days_prox(date1,date2) # count all dates between 2 dates, not including    start date
all_days=0
date = date2
while date > date1
  all_days = all_days + 1
  date = date-1;
end
all_days
end

itemarray.each do |item| $q1=hash.find_all {|k,v| v == item)    
callsnum = $q1.length
           if callsnum !=0
              if callsnum > max_totShifts_90d then
                no_solution[:maxShifts] +=1
                no_solution[:iteration_cost] += max_ShiftCost
              end
              until item == callsnum
                d1 = $q1[item-1][0]
                d2 = $q1[item][0]
                d1_daynum = d1.cwday
                d2_daynum = d2.cwday
                proximity = days_prox(d1,d2)
                if proximity < min_any_prox then
                  no_solution[:shifts_too_close] +=1
                  no_solution[:iteration_cost] += shiftTooCloseCost
                  item +=1
                elsif proximity < min_weekEnd_prox and (((6..7) === d1_daynum) and ((5..7) === d2_daynum)) then
                  no_solution[:weekends_too_close] +=1
                  no_solution[:iteration_cost] += weekendTooCloseCost
                  item +=1
                elsif (3..7) === proximity and d1_daynum <=5 and d2_daynum == 6 then
                  no_solution[:weekday_Saturday_too_close] +=1
                  no_solution[:iteration_cost] += weekdaySatTooCloseCost
                  item +=1
                elsif proximity < min_weekDay_prox and d1_daynum <=5 and d2_daynum <=5 then
                  no_solution[:weekdays_too_close] +=1
                  no_solution[:iteration_cost] += weekdayTooCloseCost
                  item +=1
                else
                  item +=1
                end
              end
            end
          end
```

so I can compare a given roster with another based on the number of "issues" it has, and the relative "costs" of those particular issues.

Once I have several roster patterns I can do:

```
rotaIt = RotaIteration.new
        rotaIt.whichiteration = rota_iteration
        rotaIt.maxShifts1 = no_solution[:maxShifts]
        rotaIt.weekdays_too_close1 = no_solution[:weekdays_too_close]
        rotaIt.weekends_too_close1 = no_solution[:weekends_too_close]
        rotaIt.shifts_too_close1 = no_solution[:shifts_too_close]
        rotaIt.messes1 = no_solution[:messes]
        rotaIt.iteration_cost1 = no_solution[:iteration_cost]
        rotaIt.rotamd51 = no_solution[:rotamd5]
        rotaIterations.push(rotaIt) # array
```

so then I can sort the `rotaIterations` array according to attributes of the `RotaIterations` class.

What am I trying to achieve?

(1) Find all dates associated with a given name 
(2) Detect conditions such as two resulting dates being within a specified distance (and do similar with 3 or 4 dates)

Apologies to Mark Thomas and others for my first post which was unclear and for their patience in untangling my question.

Comment: Your code is a bit tangled, difficult to read. In resume, what are you doing, what's the input, and the output you expect?

Comment: I know.  Part of the reason I wanted help is it doesn't read nice, so I am looking to how to simplify.   It is to check a roster pattern.  I have a list of names in itemarray, and a hash as `{date => name`} pairs.  I want to check all the `dates` that a particular `name` is rostered, and determine if the pattern is acceptable or not.  I am trying to find an elegant way of doing this.  What I currently have _works_, but it is not very clean, and i also cannot figure out how to check the condition of "no more than _x_ shifts in 14 days"

Comment: You need to better explain your question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Extracting a range of dates from your hash?

Comment: Edit previous comment as did not realise the enter key would submit the comment....apologies.

Comment: What is the format of your dates? Are they strings? `Date` objects? In general, they don't make good hash keys because hash keys must be unique. You may want to consider a different data store.

Comment: `dates` as yyyy-mm-dd `Date` objects I think.  Looks like this `[#<Date: 2018-01-02 ((2458121j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,`.  The roster runs for between 30 and 365 days.  I am very open to changing how data is stored if there is some better way.  This is my first foray into something like this and I appreciate the help I have gotten so far from SO and other sources of expertise!

Comment: Just checked properly.  `key.class` returns `Date`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (via an [edit] to the question), but you want to do the following: (1) Find all dates associated with a given name (`String` I presume); (2) Detect conditions such as two resulting dates being within a specified distance (and similar with 3 dates).

Comment: Complete rewrite of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to minimize the amount of code you end up writing and painting yourself into a complexity corner is to split things up into objects. Let's start with a Roster object:

```
require 'date'

class Roster
  attr_accessor :shifts

  def initialize(hash={})
    @shifts = hash
  end

  def add(date, name)
    raise "Date already used" if shifts[date]
    @shifts[date] = name
  end

  def names
    @shifts.values.uniq
  end

  def shifts_for(name)
    @shifts.select{|_,v| v==name}.keys
  end
end
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
roster = Roster.new( {Date.today => 'Mark', Date.today + 1 => 'busfender'} )
roster.add(Date.today + 2, 'Mark')

roster.names #=> ['Mark', 'busfender']

roster.shifts_for('Mark') #=> [#<Date: 2018-01-21>, #<Date: 2018-01-23>]

roster.shifts_for('Mark').map(&:wday) #=> [0,2]

roster.shifts_for('Mark').any?(&:sunday?) #=> true
```

The scope is a bit bigger with all the tests you want to do, but if you have any specific questions implementing your tests, you can ask a separate SO question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

**Edit**: I'll help with your second request, determining how many fall within a given period.

Assuming you use the Roster class above, you can do something like this:

```
diffs = roster.shifts_for('Claire').sort.each_cons(2).to_a.map{|(a,b)| (b-a).to_i}
#=> [2,3,2,4,5,2,5]
```

This gives you the differences between each of Claire's shifts in days. (The key is `each_cons(2)` which will group each array element with the next.) So, to check if there are 3 or more shifts within a week, you can see if there are any groups of 3 spans that sum to 7 or less:

```
diffs.each_cons(3).map(&:sum).select{|span| span <= 7}.any?
```

This will return `true` if any group of three shifts is within a span of 7 days.

**Edit 2**: I just noticed your edit which states you have this information in MySQL. Just about all the logic above should be done in the database (perhaps using ActiveRecord, DataMapper, or sequel). By extracting to a hash and performing hash operations, you are making it less efficient and requiring more code.

Comment: Thanks for these extremely helpful answers.

Comment: Try again: So:running the logic in MySQL:1) I cannot generate more than about 100 rotas in a table to try and analyse as I run out of space (something to do with InnoDB page size?) 2) running repeated generates of smaller numbers of columns so I can extract the roster columns to Ruby and validate it, compared to extracting the hash once andthen run my random generation of the roster and check it against conditions with my old program takes much longer.  i.e. ran out of patience long vs 5.6 seconds.  Still, thanks for your help.